# Express Validator: How parameters passed to validator functions

Tags: node.js, validation, express, express-validator

I am curious how the parameters are passed to validator middleware, the excerpt is taken from [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#express-validator), e.g., **programming_language** is passed to check() function.

```
const { check, oneOf, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
app.post('/start-freelancing', oneOf([
  check('programming_language').isIn(['javascript', 'java', 'php']),
  check('design_tools').isIn(['photoshop', 'gimp'])
]), (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    validationResult(req).throw();

    // yay! we're good to start selling our skilled services :)))
    res.json(...);
  } catch (err) {
    // Oh noes. This user doesn't have enough skills for this...
    res.status(422).json(...);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
check('programming_language')
```

'programming_language' is a request parameter. No need to pass anything separately. It picks up from

```
req.body.programming_language
req.cookies.programming_language
req.headers.programming_language
req.params.programming_language
req.query.programming_language
```

Same thing for 'design_tools'

```
req.body.design_tools
req.cookies.design_tools
req.headers.design_tools
req.params.design_tools
req.query.design_tools
```